# A topology on a set

Tags: general-topology

I have a set $Y=\{0,1,2\}$.

Why is $\sigma=\{\phi,Y,\{0\},\{1,2\}\}$ a topology on the set Y even though there is no intersection between the $0$ and $\{1,2\}$?

Comment: The power set is a topology. Not all topologies are the power set. And what is $x$ here? Did you mean $Y$?

Comment: I'm unsure as to why this has been down voted?

Comment: @Karl Hovering over the downvote option one of the suggestions for why to downvote reads "*This question does not show any research effort; it is not clear or not useful.*"  I would expect that after any bit of reading on the topic would show that there are topologies other than the powerset.  (for trivial example the empty topology).

Comment: @thomasandrews good spot, fixed!

Comment: @jmoravitz I suppose what I was trying to get at was: in one of my previous questions I was told something was not a topology because their was no intersection between two sets or something like that and I was wondering then how it was possible for any other than the power set to be a topology.

Comment: @jmoravitz Basically I was looking for distinguishing features regarding what it means to be a topology because I am really struggling with this concept.

Comment: Always try to put such thoughts *into the question.* As it is, it really does look like you think the power set is the definition of topology. Many here might not have read you other question. Treat each question as if you are communicating with people for the first time. @Aljabra

Comment: @thomasandrews thanks for the tip